# Wireless Mouse and keyboard combo freezing randomly for a few seconds

Tags: updates, keyboard, mouse, input

### The issue

Every few minutes the mouse frezees in it's place, or they keyboard stops responding. this lasts for around 2 or 3 seconds, and returns to normal.

The keyboard does the same thing, but if a key was pressed it keeps auto-repeating (so in the middle of a sentence it suddenly gives you 5 letters of whatever you were typing).

It feels like when the mouse or keyboard are low on battery, but it works fine in windows, and it started happening right after a big software update, so I don't think it's a hardware issue.

### My system

I'm running elementary OS Loki, on a desktop PC with an A4tech wireless mouse+keyboard combo (9100F). It works fine on windows and worked just as well on elementary a few days ago.

### When it started

This is happening since a few days ago, when I updated the whole system (apt upgrade). There was a kernel update, some mesa packages, and some elementary updates (haven't updated in some time). I can provide an apt log if it would help, but it's a long list, so it probably won't narrow it down too much.

### Troubleshooting

Maybe it's something related to usb suspension? I'm running on a desktop, so I shouldn't have aggressive power settings doing stuff like that.

Could the CPU or disk have big spikes which make it unresponsive? I do not notice the HDD light blinking, and I'm not running any software out of the ordinary (VSCode+Chrome+Webpack-dev-server, same as before when it was running ok).

I don't know how to try to debug this issue, it feels completely random. How can I get more information about what's happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
sudo su
echo 2 | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/autosuspend >/dev/null
echo on | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/level >/dev/null
```

This should disable USB-autosuspend.

Comment: Thank you! The usb device for my mouse+keyboard was on 2 instead of 0 on /power/autosuspend, so maybe this will solve it. Is the setting permanent? It's still weird if it gets fixed cause it stops working when actively using the device, but who knows. Will report back and accept answer if it worked.